# Android application development

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Android and I was trying to make a simple application on Android and this "activity_main" error is not getting cleared. I have gone through all the available answers

```
package com.example.theoldyerwa;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.R;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What ""activity_main" error ". Can you be more precise?

Comment: I think its .R file problem....

Comment: You need to be more precise, post your stacktrace and code so we can help you

Comment: just clean and rebuild the project.it will remove.

Comment: post some code. We cant tell if we cant see what you did wrong

Comment: @AdamRadomski: Activity_main cannot be resolved or its not a field.

Comment: "Activity_main" should be always lowercase. Did you change anything in it? do you refer somewhere to activity_main as Activity_main?

Comment: If you imported anything new, or anything that includes R then delete them. Clean your project and check if it cleaned

Comment: People are still just guessing your problem here, paste your code and stacktrace in code blocks, edit your question. Show some effort and people will help you

Comment: @AdamRadomski: i haven't changed anything, i just finished setting up everything and created a project, that's when the errors came.

Answer (score 0):

1) Where does your layout file exist? is it under layout folder then shouldn't it be

R.layout.activity_main

2) You still have to import your projects R file

com.new.yourproject.R;

3) R file is automatically generated if there's no error in your code. Sometimes when you get can't resolve R file error means you have problem somewhere else in the project. Try clean project.